# Storyboard connected properties not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Im really confused because my problem may sound silly, i try to explain it clear - when i add anything on storyboard view controller it has no effect. And obvious, my `viewController` set properly to a controller, that manage storyboard scene. I adding anything -  `buttons`, `imageViews`, it doesn't appear on a screen at all.

Also i want to add, i never seen such problem before recent Xcode update, when storyboard scene's become "large" and there is single scene for any device (600x600).

That issue literally drive me crazy, i can manage interface objects programmatically but i don't want to, because i use to work with Storyboard. Could you please write some advice or solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add positioning constraints. By default, it will leave elements where they are, so they might be cut off. Also make sure what should be in the background is `Sent to Back`.

Comment: Thanks, how silly am i looking for now! You save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the auto layout this interfirindo or even if you this in the right view.